# I am getting unexpected <head/> in my xml file how to remove that tag

Tags: php, html, xml, codeigniter-2

I am generating an api for trip advisor but while sending the xml file an unexpected  tag i am getting in production.but i am not getting in localhost.
i have generated xml file using DOM document.
here a copy of my code.

```
   $data=$this->property_model->getreservations_data($start_date,$end_date);

    $xml= new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml->FormatOutput=true;
    $Reservations=$xml->createElement('Reservations');
    $Reservations=$xml->appendChild($Reservations);

    foreach ($data as $key) {
        $Reservation=$xml->createElement('Reservation');
        $Reservation->setAttribute('property_id',$key['prop_id']);
        $Reservation->setAttribute('reservation_id',$key['booking_id']);
        $Reservation=$Reservations->appendChild($Reservation);

        $EmailAddress=$xml->createElement('EmailAddress',$key['email']);
        $EmailAddress=$Reservation->appendChild($EmailAddress);
        $fromdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($key['travel_from_date']));
        $ArrivalDate=$xml->createElement('ArrivalDate',$fromdate);
        $ArrivalDate=$Reservation->appendChild($ArrivalDate);
        $todate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($key['travel_to_date']));
        $DepartureDate=$xml->createElement('DepartureDate',$todate);
        $DepartureDate=$Reservation->appendChild($DepartureDate);

        if ($key['order_status']=='Success') {
            $Status=$xml->createElement('Status');
            $Status->setAttribute('value','reserved');
            $Status=$Reservation->appendChild($Status);
        }else{

            $Status=$xml->createElement('Status');
            $Status->setAttribute('value','cancelled');
            $Status=$Reservation->appendChild($Status);
        }
    }
    echo $xml->saveXML();

}
```

output in production:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<head/><Reservations><Reservation property_id="998" reservation_id="1998"><EmailAddress>kunal31393@gmail.com</EmailAddress><ArrivalDate>2015-12-07</ArrivalDate><DepartureDate>2018-05-06</DepartureDate><Status value="reserved"/>
```

output in localhost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reservations><Reservation property_id="290" reservation_id="10292"><EmailAddress>yogeshb@gmail.com</EmailAddress><ArrivalDate>2016-10-20</ArrivalDate><DepartureDate>2017-05-17</DepartureDate><Status value="reserved"/>
```

Comment: None of that XML is valid because it is missing closing tags.

Comment: I think OP have jus pasted the part of the codes. As you can see fields inside Reservations has opening and corresponding closing tags.

Comment: it has closing tags <Reservations><Reservation property_id="290" reservation_id="10292"><EmailAddress>yogeshb@gmail.com</EmailAddress><ArrivalDate>2016-10-20</ArrivalDate><DepartureDate>2017-05-17</DepartureDate><Status value="reserved"/></Reservation></Reservations>

Comment: how to remove that <head/> tag even i have used str_replace() function then also its not removing

Comment: This does not happen with the source you provided: https://eval.in/843259

Answer (score 0):

you need to try sending xml with proper content type
set

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

Comment: it works but showing error



error on line 1 at column 7: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document